# Invalid salt Error in autentication process in nodejs

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, authentication, passwords

Am new to javascript and nodejs, I wrote a code to do authentication of the user from the password and salt present in database, Below is the code in nodejs were i receive a usercode and password and i retrieve the data from database and compare the password and salt present in DB with the received password.

The salt stored in DB is generated by base64 format.

```
var Bcrypt = require('bcrypt');   
var pg = require('pg');
var usercode = 'tarun';
var clientid='214057357158656';
var password='tarun';
var connectionString = "postgres://dbusername:password@localhost:5432/USCProduction";
console.log('connectin to DB');
var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect(function(err) {   

    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    var Query ='select password, salt from muser, mclient where usercode='+"'"+usercode+"'"+' and muser.clientid='+clientid+' and muser.clientid=mclient.clientid and mclient.status=1';
    console.log('executing query',Query);
    client.query(Query, function(err, result) {

   if(err){
       console.log('Error in executing Query');
       client.end();
   } else {
       console.log(result.rows);
       var passinDB=result.rows[0].password;
       var saltinDB=result.rows[0].salt;
       console.log('passwordinDB : ',passinDB);
       console.log('saltinDB : ',saltinDB);
 client.end();
    Bcrypt.hash(passinDB, saltinDB, function(err, hash) {
        if(err) {
                return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log(hash);
    Bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err) {
                return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log('do they match?', isMatch);
    });

});
   }
    });
});
```

Am facing the following error while ececuting the code

```
passwordinDB :  StAxL1r3bb/5k/6D6+BulwxhXFs=
saltinDB :  FOhs8crXyO8=
    [Error: Invalid salt. Salt must be in the form of: $Vers$log2(NumRounds)$saltvalue]
```

its unable to find number of rounds of the salt or any other i may be missing in the code ,how to over come this error.

Thank You..!!

Answer (score 5):

It's a data type issue!

`saltRounds` should be of type `Number`. The issue can arise if you're using an `.env` file to store the value - all values are stored as `String`s in the env file.

In this case either assign the value in the code `const saltRounds = 10` or coerce the env variable to a number `const saltRounds = Number(process.env.BCRYPT_COST);`.

Better still, since this value is not about to change, it can directly be passed to the hash function

`const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);`

Answer (score 4):

A readable way to generate:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")

const hash = async (text, size) => {
    try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(size);

        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(text, salt);

        return hash
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line,

> Salt must be in the form of: $Vers$log2(NumRounds)$saltvalue]

**$Vers** is bcrypt_id 
**$log2(NumRounds)** is a parameter that tells it how many times to execute that internal hash function.

So you need to generate salt and has password in this way:

```js
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash("any_password", salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB.
    });
});
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 2):

convert saltinDB to int

```
saltinDB = parseInt(saltinDB)
```

Comment: Cool. And, also `Number` would work 2.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution with promises

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    .then(
        salt => {
            bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
                .then(hash => {
                    console.log(`INFO: Hash generated: ${hash}`)
                        // Store hash in your password DB.
                });
        }
    ).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Console

```
jmendoza@jmendoza-ThinkPad-T420:~/IdeaProjects/NodeJS-API-Course/Intermediate-Node-API$ npm run dev

> intermediate-node-api@1.0.0 dev /home/jmendoza/IdeaProjects/NodeJS-API-Course/Intermediate-Node-API
> nodemon src/app.js

[nodemon] 2.0.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/app.js`
INFO: A NodeJS API is listining on port: 3000
INFO: mongoDB, Atlas. Connected
INFO: SALT: 15
POST /api/v1/users 200 28.146 ms - 40
INFO: Hash generated: $2b$10$1/4o27jmhscGEgTyF54NQurLbZvXI9zFROZKhlm0EoHsBE24NTAVu
```

You can see the complete code in my repository:

https://github.com/JonathanM2ndoza/NodeJS-API-Course/blob/master/Advanced-Node-API/src/modules/encrypt.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    .then(
        salt => {
            bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
                .then(hash => {
                    console.log(`INFO: Hash generated: ${hash}`)
                        // Store hash in your password DB.
                });
        }
    ).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

this now worked for me